# Increment in Manipulate does not seem correct

Tags: manipulate

I am reading the documentation for the Manipulate command and I've done this code:

```
Manipulate[Row[{n, "+", m, "=", n + m}],
 {n, 1/2, 1/3, 1/144},
 {m, 1/2, 1/3, 1/144}
 ]
```

However, when I do one click on the + sign to increment n, I get the following picture.

[image]

I think it should increment 1/2 by 1/144 to get
$$\frac12+\frac{1}{144}=\frac{72}{144}+\frac{1}{144}=\frac{73}{144},$$
but it gets 71/144 instead. Something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}$, the increment is negative, and you get
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{144}=\frac{71}{144}$$

Comment: Oh my goodness, that I didn't see. My fault. Thanks for the answer.